# How to stop other scripts from updating my prompt?

Tags: customization, virtualenv, command-prompt, zsh, prompt

I created my own custom prompt script in zsh and it works great but when I start a virtualenv in python (e.g. $WORKON [venv]) my prompt gets updated twice because the activate script in my venev gets ran which contains the code to update my prompt as well as my custom prompt script which contains essentially the same code.  I pretty much copied the prompt functions out of the activate script and put it in my custom prompt script so that I could change the colors and placement.  I am getting duplicates, obviously.

To work around this issue I could change the activate script in each of my venvs but that seems tedious.  If activate script is updating my prompt, I would like my prompt script to be able to see these changes and then access and manipulate the changes to my desired effect.  If I was able to do this I could delete out the duplicate code in my prompt script, let activate script do its thing, and then have my prompt script tweak the update activate script made.

Below is a dumbed down version of my actual prompt.zsh but it should be enough to demonstrate my issue.

prompt.zsh

```
add_venv_info () {
if [ -z "$VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT" ] ; then
    VIRT_ENV_TXT=""
    if [ "x" != x ] ; then
        VIRT_ENV_TXT=""
    else
        if [ "`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`" = "__" ] ; then
            # special case for Aspen magic directories
            # see http://www.zetadev.com/software/aspen/
            VIRT_ENV_TXT="[`basename \`dirname \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"\``]"
        elif [ "$VIRTUAL_ENV" != "" ]; then
            VIRT_ENV_TXT="(`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`)"
        fi
    fi
    if [ "${VIRT_ENV_TXT}" != "" ]; then
       echo ${VIRT_ENV_TXT}" "
    fi
fi

export PROMPT='\n%F{red}`add_venv_info`%~'
```

activate

```
if [ -z "${VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT-}" ] ; then
_OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1="$PS1"
if [ "x" != x ] ; then
    PS1="$PS1"
else
if [ "`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`" = "__" ] ; then
    # special case for Aspen magic directories
    # see http://www.zetadev.com/software/aspen/
    PS1="[`basename \`dirname \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"\``] $PS1"
else
    PS1="(`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`)$PS1"
fi
fi
export PS1
```

If I want to activate venenv "py3" I run the following command:

`$ $WORKON py3`

Assuming I'm in the home directory (~), my prompt changes from this:

~

to this:

(py3)(py3)~

the first (py3) isn't red but the second one is. I understand what is happening, I just don't know how to fix it without constantly making changes to my activate script.

Answer (score 0):

After reading more I found that there isn't an easy way to do this, however, any plugin or script that updates your prompt should have an environment variable that you can set that will disable the prompt update but still set the variables for you to access and update into your custom prompt.

For example, virtualenv checks for the variable $VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT. I had to add `$VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT="1"` in my .zshrc file in order to disable the update prompt in the activate script.  Next, I changed my add_venv_info function to:

```
add_venv_info () {
local virtualenv_path="$VIRTUAL_ENV"
if [[ -n $virtualenv_path && -n $VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT ]]; then
    echo `basename $virtualenv_path`
fi
```

}

Now everything works great.  I am a newbie to computer science so please forgive my stupid questions.

see the docs at http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference.html

Comment: You can also use `virtualenvwrapper` for more customizable and fine-grained hooks.